# React slide transition between routes, where route components are of different heights

Tags: reactjs, animation, routes, transition, slide

I am trying to create a "multi-directional" website that allows you to scroll down and at the click of a navigation button slide the current displayed component out of the screen and the relevant new component into the screen.

I want to be able to slide the new component where the focus on that component is at the top('hero section') and slide the old component out at the height position where the user made the click to slide.

I have achieved the slide effect but am not able to get the new component to focus on the top('hero section'). Instead it will perform the slide at the same height position of the old component where the click was made.

To perform the slide I am making use of:
 -react-router-dom
 -react-router-page-transition

Where the "Switch" has a containing element of "PageTransition" that applies the transition effect to each "Route"

Any ideas on how I can achieve the slide animation effect where the new component slides in from anywhere on the previous component and the new components focus is at the top('hero section')?

Thanks in advance!

```js
//Switch Container that is called within App.js
export default withRouter(function SwitchContainer({location}){
 return(
   <PageTransition timeout={1000}>
    <Switch location={location}>
     <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
     <Route exac path='/about-us' component={AboutUsPage} />
     <Route exact path='/contact-us' component={ContactUsPage} />
    </Switch>
   </PageTransition>
 )
}
)
```

```css
.landing-page{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.landing-page.transition-appear{
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.landing-page.transition-appear.transition-appear-active{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.landing-page.transition-leave{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.landing-page.transition-leave.transition-leave-active{
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.about-us-page{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

.about-us-page.transition-appear{
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.about-us-page.transition-appear.transition-appear-active{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.about-us-page.transition-leave{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.about-us-page.transition-leave.transition-leave-active{
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-us-page{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.contact-us-page.transition-appear{
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.contact-us-page.transition-appear.transition-appear-active{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.contact-us-page.transition-leave{
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.contact-us-page.transition-leave.transition-leave-active{
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Please share any relevant code snippets, to create a [mcve]. Also, I think some parts of your question need clarification: "*Where the has a containing element*[...]" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I apologise this is my first asked question on stackoverflow.. I have made the edits and I hope this clarifies the question @dennlinger